# Underfull \hbox (badness 2005) message

Tags: badness

This message of warning appears at the bibliography, which says:

```
\bibitem{Cat04}
M.~Catalani.
\newblock Generalized bivariate {F}ibonacci polynomials. Preprint, 2004.
\newblock \arxiv{math/0211366v2}
```

In the log file:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 2005) in paragraph at lines 962--965
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 M. Cata-lani. Gen-er-al-ized bi-vari-ate Fi-bonacci poly-no-
mi-als. Preprint, 2004.
[]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes I have the cite command and the pdf file.In pdf file the line looks like not completly filled as you said. I hope it is not a problem.

Comment: the `badness` message is just a warning.  in this case, it is telling you that the reported line is stretched beyond what tex considers "acceptable".  the reason is that the `\arxiv` reference can't be broken in this situation.  (urls and similar "code strings" are highly susceptible to this problem, and there isn't any really good solution. in tugboat, we often set bibliographies ragged right to avoid wretched spacing, but that's not always acceptable.  another approach, equally objectionable, is to force a line break after the date, leaving one short line.)